# Wait for SQL Server code to be fully executed before proceeding (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I have the following example code:

```
protected void SampleButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in items) //items - contain about 20 000 elements
    {
        MyClassSQLManager.RunSomeSampleSQLUpdateCommand(item.Id);
        // SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery: UPDATE Items SET Flag = 1 WHERE Id = {0}
    }  

    MyGridViewWithItems.DataBind();
    ShowMessage("OK");
}
```

This method executes in a few seconds, page finishes to load and I see "OK" message. The problem is that the T-SQL code is still running and it processed about 10% records by that time.

Is there a way to wait until the SQL Server database finishes proceeding the code, so I can bind `MyGridViewWithItems` then and only then show "OK" message?

Comment: What are those classes? None of the is ADO.NET. In fact, the name `MySQLManager` suggests that this is *not* a SQL Server question at all.

Comment: is `RunSomeSampleSQLUpdateCommand` async?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos This is my class which executes SqlCommand on the database (with SqlConnection). Sorry for the name, I just used some sample names here. Lei Yang no, it's not async

Comment: @user2441297 what is `MySQLManager.RunSomeSampleSQLUpdateCommand` and what does it do? Where is its code? It's impossible to help find bugs in *invisible* code.  Could there be an *exception* perhaps that got swallowed by a `catch {}`.

Comment: Cannot you run your command for all items at once? `UPDATE Items SET Flag = 1 WHERE Id IN ({your items});` That's going to be more efficient. Now it seems that you're sending `{x}` requests to database in order to make these updates.

Comment: @user2441297 ADO.NET just doesn't behave in the way you describe. Anyway, executing one update at a time is *very* inefficient. A better solution would be to use an `IN ()` clause, although you'd have to split the 20K elements. into batches of aroung 2000. An even better solution would be to insert all that data into a staging table and execute `UPDATE Items from Items inner join temp_Ids  on Items.ID=temp_IDs.ID`